# custom controls are overlapping infowindow on Google Map Apiv3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls, infowindow

I'm using Google maps V3 API . I've added a custom control on the Map. Its having a width of 350px and height 300px.
When i open infoWindow on Map, custom control will overlap infoWindow.

is there any way to put infoWindow on top of the custom control?

Comment: It will be very much helpful to answer if you would post the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some code in your question that demonstrates your issue, we're more or less just guessing at what your problem is.

Looking at the reference documentation for [`google.maps.MapPanes`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes) tells us that the InfoWindow lives within the top-most layer, but it's not clear what pane these  [`google.maps.Map.controls`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) fall under.

What you're trying to do may not be possible, by design. I'd say it was a purposeful decision by the Google Maps team to ensure that the map controls are never obscured.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. As mentioned above - there is no way to do it with a custom control, although there is solution using Custom Overlay.

[This answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231115/2397703) should give enough information to solve this. The solution there displays overlay above markers, but in the same way it would be displayed under the `InfoWindow` layer.

Answer (score 0):

Push map (which includes the infowindows) in front of the controls on infowindow open and pull it back on its closing.

css:

```
.infoopen div[aria-label="Map"]{
 z-index:1!important;
}
```

js:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
  if(!infowindows[marker.myOwnTarget].anchor) var openme=true;

  $.each(markers,function(){
   infowindows[this.myOwnTarget].close();
   // show controls and legend on infowindow closing by clicking any marker
   $(".map").removeClass("infoopen");
  });

  if(openme){
   infowindows[marker.myOwnTarget].open(thamap, marker);
   // hide controls and legend on info open
   $(".map").addClass("infoopen");

   google.maps.event.addListener(infowindows[marker.myOwnTarget], 'closeclick', function () {
    // show controls and legend on close click
    $(".map").removeClass("infoopen");
   });
  }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You have asked "is there any way to put infoWindow on top of the custom control?", If I understand your question correctly then you need to add z-index to your infowindow properties, to show it above/top of the customer control.

You can add the below code to achieve this.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        zIndex: 1000
      });
```

Comment: this won't work because of the way the panes are layered, if you increase the zindex of the infowindow pane, the entire map is then placed above the controls